# How to read spring cloud gateway paths defined in yml?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I want to read the path attribute defined in yml cofiguration of spring cloud gateway app in filter code:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: DEMO gateway service
          uri: ${DEMO_URL}
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/demo/**, /api/get/**
```

How can I read these paths in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this using the property file that is provided by spring cloud gateway i.e., **org.springframework.cloud.gateway.config.GatewayProperties.java**